# Solving $\ln$ equations

Tags: calculus

$e^{2x} = e^{x} + 1 $

My attempt :

$e^{2x} - e^{x} = 1$

$e^{x} (e^{2} - 1) = 1$

$e^x = \frac{1}{e^{2} - 1} $

$\ln e^x = \ln \frac{1}{e^{2} - 1}$

$ x = -1.16$

Why is my method wrong ?

Comment: The third line is not true. It should be $e^x(e^x - 1) = 1$.

Comment: Does it not look like a quadratic equation to you?

Comment: Write $y=e^x$ and note that $y^2=e^{2x}$.

Answer (score 1):

$e^{2x} \not = e^x * e^2 = e^{x+2}$. Furthermore, $e^{2x}  = (e^x)^2$.

You'd want your factorization to be $$e^x(e^x - 1) = 1$$ if you want to solve it by factoring then dividing then manipulating.

Answer (score 1):

First solve for $t=e^x$ (it's a quadratic equation in disguise!). $t^2=t+1$ gives $t=\frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}$

Now, could both of those be reasonable values for $e^x$?